# Save user input from Textbox to sql Table in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, billing

I am making an Ecommerce Checkout page with billing information, and I want to save whatever the user inputs in the textbox and save that to my customerB table in my visual studio database. Clicking the button does not seem to do anything, and I do not know what else can work. It seems not difficult and i have found c# code on youtube videos but not VB.

```
    Protected Sub btnAccountBilling_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)         Handles btnAccountBilling.Click

    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strConnectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("UStoreConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim connSQL As New SqlConnection(strConnectionString)
    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, connSQL)

    cmdSQL = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO CustomerB(FirstName, LastName, Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip, Phone, Email) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Address1, @Address2, @City, @State, @Zip, @Phone, @Email)", connSQL)

    cmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", tbbFirstName.Text)
    cmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", tbbLastName.Text)
    cmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address1", tbbAddress1.Text)
    cmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address2", tbbAddress2.Text)
    cmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", tbbCity.Text)
    cmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", ddlbState.Text)
    cmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", tbbZip.Text)
    cmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", tbbPhone.Text)
    cmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", tbbEmail.Text)

    connSQL.Open()
    cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connSQL.Close()

End Sub
```

All my textbox values and button are correctly named so I am not sure what is wrong

Comment: What happens when you single-step in the debugger?

Comment: What means "it does not do anything"? Do you get an exception? Use the debugger. Show also your `Page_Load`.

Comment: NO i did not get any exceptions, my button is <asp:Button ID="btnAccountBilling" runat="server" Text="Continue" CssClass="button" /> it just does not populate to the database. my page load is        Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If (Page.IsPostBack) Then
            lblConfirm.Text = ("Your data has been saved")
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: Side-note: why do you say "Your data has been saved" before the data was actually saved? Do that in the button-click handler.

Comment: OH i meant to put that as page_loadComplete, I also tried doing a simple response.redirect on the button click, but it still did not redirect me. Do i need to have a page_load function?